# QRCODE Com problemas Ireport

Tags: java, sql, ireport, qrcode

Meu QRcode está imprimindo da seguinte maneira no iReport, desta maneira está com problemas:

[image: QRcode Gerado com problemas]

O Correto seria neste formato:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já realizei todas as configurações necessárias para o funcionamento do mesmo.

1 - Adicionei as bibliotecas necessárias

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2- Adicionei o Field passando a expressão da Imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3 - Minha query está da seguinte maneira

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na query do SQL eu estava utilizando o campo CRC16 sem nenhum tratamento, esse campo possuía um espaço em branco no final, ocasionando o problema, pois o código estava quebrando.

Realizei a seguinte alteração no campo, para retirar os espaços, com isso o problema foi resolvido e o Qrcode foi gerado com sucesso.

RTRIM(LTRIM(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),CRC16))) AS URL1

[image: QRcode gerado em meu sistema]